# PhpStorm's "Listen for Debug Connections" button is not active

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, roadrunner

At some point the button to enable debugging became inactive. What can be the problem and how to cure it?

I tried to change port and other settings, rebooted the machine.

I searched for information on the net, but found nothing useful.

[image]

Comment: My best guess -- something is wrong with your PHP Interpreter in PhpStorm settings. Double check that (if you have it at all, if it is selected for this project; perhaps try deleting and creating it again). No other ideas right now.

Comment: Do you mean during debugging? You may run into a gateway timeout.